# Issue releasing data with core-data (CFDATA keep growing)

Tags: core-data, memory-management, allocation, nsmanagedobject

I have a memory problem with data-core. In a view controller I load an image (data) from a NSManagedObject, then display it, and next go to the next page to load another image, and so on.
The problem is that I can't release the data, in allocation tool keeps in CFDATA(store). Here is part of the code:

```
        ComicImage *cimg = [page getImageData];


        NSData *data=cimg.imageData ;
```

ComicImage is a NSManagedObject, getImageData returns the ComicImage with the image to display.

Releasing data deletes the image in core-data, and I can't load it again (crash).  I have tried refreshObject:mergeChanges, but no result; [context reset] crashes the app.
Any idea?
Thanks.

Comment: Is this really a problem, does this lead to memory warnings? Core data does the memory juggling for you of its managed objects.

Comment: Yeah, eventually the app crashes.

Answer (score 3):

If you use a UIImage/NSImage in a managed object's property to hold the image, then the memory management of the image is out of your hands as image classes will retain the image in memory as long as the managed object is alive in memory.

The preferred method for dealing with large images is to store them in an external file and just record a path to the file in Core Data. That way you can load and unload the image as needed.

Comment: Ok, it will take me some work, but I'm going to try it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and managed to solve it.

The Allocations instrument would show 'CFData (store)' persisting in memory whenever I performed a `save` operation on an NSManagedObjectContext, even after releasing the NSManagedObjects. When loading other NSManagedObjects the 'CFData (store)' would grow in size.

Calling `reset` on my NSManagedObjectContext solved the issue, I do this after releasing my current NSManagedObjects, and after a save operation the 'CFData (store)' happily disappears from memory.

Also, you can manage your own properties in a NSManagedObject. You can override `didTurnIntoFault` and release your properties there. `willTurnIntoFault` is also an alternative, `dealloc` shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 0):

You say that you go to the next "page" to open a new image.  If you are using a navigation controller, the previous pages will be retained until popped.  I would recommend not using a UINavigationController for this situation.